# When can mutex->__data.__nusers be 4294967295?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, mutex, recursive-mutex

I have a core dump file where `pthread_mutex_destroy()` has returned an error, probably because in the `pthread_mutex_t` data structure the `__nusers` field is set to 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF). Here are the full values:

```
mMutex = {
    __data = {
        __lock = 0,
        __count = 0,
        __owner = 0,
        __nusers = 4294967295,
        __kind = 1,
        __spins = 0,
        __elision = 0,
        __list = {
            __prev = 0x0,
            __next = 0x0
        }
    },
    __size = '\000' <repeats 12 times>, "\377\377\377\377\001", '\000' <repeats 22 times>,
    __align = 0
}
```

This is a recursive mutex. The code is running on a RHEL 8 system.

So at first glance this looks like `__nusers` was somehow decremented once too often. But I don't see how this could happen - calling `pthread_mutex_unlock()` without locking first leaves the `__nusers` count at 0 (it returns `EPERM`, but [there shouldn't be any undefined behavior involved for a recursive mutex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)).

Under what circumstances would `__nusers` become essentially "negative"?

Comment: What error is returned by `pthread_mutex_destroy`?

Comment: I suspect mutex has been used before was initialized or after it was destroyed (destroyed when lock is acquired or locked after destruction).

Comment: @G.M. I don't know the exact error code, since it's optimized out in the core dump :-/ I only know that it's not 0. But if I understand https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_mutex_destroy.c.html#__pthread_mutex_destroy correctly, the function will return EBUSY for a recursive mutex if __nusers is not 0.

Comment: Are you saying that the program crashed and dumped core *in* `pthread_mutex_destroy()`, or, as the question text seems to indicate, that you obtained a core dump from some point after `pthread_mutex_destroy()` returned an error code?  If the latter, then have you indeed neither captured the return value (which should then be readable from the core dump) nor used `perror()` to emit a characteristic message to `stderr`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: the crash (actually the abort() call) is after `pthread_mutex_destroy()`, in my code. That code checks whether the return value is 0, but unfortunately does not print the return value in any way. And even though there's a local variable storing the return value, that variable has been optimized out by the compiler, so I can't see its value in the debugger.

Comment: Well, as a matter of style and code quality, I would recommend that you precede any call to `abort()` with emitting some kind of diagnostic to `stderr`. You might find the `perror()` function appropriate for this, but because `pthread_mutex_destroy()` returns an error number instead of setting the `errno` variable, you would need to set `errno` yourself.  Alternatively, you could use `strerror()` to get the meat of a diagnostic.  I would suggest putting in such a change now, and seeing what it tells you when the failure next occurs.

Comment: You might also consider running your program under valgrind, as memory corruption from overrunning object bounds is a possible explanation, but do understand that Valgrind cannot catch all such cases.

Comment: You should also consider working on a [mre].  In part because presenting one would help us help you, but more, in this case, because the exercise is a powerful debugging technique in its own right.